# Powershell tasks not compiling template expression on AzDO yml

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I’m trying to understand how variable template reference files work on AzDO. It seems it’s easy enough on Bash but really struggling to get it to work on PS.

I have a variable file:

```
variables:
  astring:     'fghj'
```

And a YAML file that simply prints out the ‘astring’:
variables:

```
  template: variableTemplate.yml
  something: '123'
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: Write-Host ${{ variables.astring }}
```

I do not get any output running as above. However, if I was to change the script from "Write-Host ${{ variables.astring }}" to "Write-Host ${{ variables.something }}" then I get '123' so it looks like the reference file is not being compiled at all?

I fear I am missing something obvious but I am struggling, Any suggestions on how to get it working please?

Thanks in advance.

Edit - As requested by @Shayki Abramczyk, file structures:

- Top Level Repo:

  - folder1:

    - variableMaster.yml
    - variableTemplate.yml

Yaml files:

variableMaster.yml:

```
pool: Release-WRR-DevLAN-Win
variables:
  template: folder1/variableTemplate.yml
  something: '123'

steps:
- checkout: self
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: Write-Host ${{variables.astring}}
```

variableTemplate.yml:

```
variables:
  astring: tyu
```

On my initial example, the variable template reference was not correct; I had to put in the full folder path (folder1/variableTemplate.yml) for it to be seen by a command such as test-path. This is strange to me as I thought the variable yml path was relative to the main yaml file so I shouldn't have to put in the folder name as they are both under the same folder? However, I still get the same issue when using the same folder path (ie, variable not resolving)

Comment: It should works. is the `variableTemplate.yml` file is in the same folder as the second YAML?

Comment: Hi, I've done it both ways - in the same folder and a seperate folder and I get the same results each time

Comment: Share your whole YAML files and files structure.

Comment: Shared in the original post askign the question. Thanks.